# Does reverting a specific commit from the original branch impact the integration branch?

Tags: git

I have a branch called `devbranch` and a branch `master`. If I cherry picked a commit `XYZ` from `devbranch` to `master` branch, and then I revert or reset the `XYZ` commit from the `devbranch`, would that revert or reset impact, revert or rest commit `XYZ` from the `master` branch?

Comment: Are you asking whether you now need to revert from the `master` branch if you want to get rid of the commit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick review of some key concepts:

- A git repository is made up of commits.
- Each commit contains a snapshot of all your files, and some metadata including zero or more (but normally one or two) links to *parent* commits.
- History is examined by working *backwards* from a known commit to its parents.
- A branch is just a pointer to a commit, giving you somewhere you can look at history backwards from.

Now some specifics:

- `git cherry-pick` looks at a commit, compares it to its parent, and then reproduces the same changes somewhere else *as a new commit*. The new commit is not related to the original in any way.
- `git revert` does the same thing, but "in reverse": it compares a commit to its parent, and then applies the *opposite* of that change. Again, it creates a brand new commit, which is not related to the original.

So, to come back to your question:

- You have two independent commits - the original commit, "XYZ" which you committed on "devbranch"; and a *different* commit created when you cherry picked onto "master"
- When you run `git revert`, you will create a *third* commit, undoing the changes of "XYZ"

As an alternative, you can "rewrite history", which actually means *creating a new history* (I like to think of it like going into a parallel universe). For instance, you could use an "interactive rebase" to replay all the commits *except for* the one you want to "erase from history".

Answer (score 2):

Reverting a commit simply creates an opposite commit on the current branch. It doesn't affect other branches. You'll need to revert the cherry-pick commit on the master branch as well, or you can cherry-pick the reversion commit from the dev branch. It's all the same with respect to the outcome, but it depends on how you want your history recorded.